# How to flash code from external SD card to internal memory and boot the image?

Tags: sd-card, development

With the ELB-REV4 board, which has both internal memory and an SD card slot, once my application works fine, I need to boot using an image on the external SD card image. I want to flash the complete SD card image to internal memory.

How can I flash my code from external SD card to internal memory, and boot the image from internal memory?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running from an SD card, then `mmcblk0` represents the SD card.

This Linux command will flash from the SD card to internal memory:

```
busybox dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

Comment: That helped, and Thanks. Regards Saurabh Khare

Comment: If you find the answer useful, click the up pointing gray arrowhead at left; if solves the problem, and is the best answer which does, click the checkmark over there as well.